# Using Hyperledger Composer Documentation to Deploy Fabric Locally and Getting Errors

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to deploy fabric using composer (composer, docker, docker -composer). I have been able install most of the items using composer documentation and some online tutorials. However, when I try to start my network using the following command, I get error messages that follow the commandlines. May be someone can help with this:

**Commandlines**
composer network start --networkName block-track --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card

**Error Messages**
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
ComError: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Command failed

Comment: The fact you got request_timeout implies your fabric is running, I would suggest looking at https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md and searching for request_timeout for possibile solutions

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the fabric network is running good but composer-cli can't get a response from a fabric network. Sometimes it depends on network connectivity.

you need to restart fabric network by **./stopFaric.sh** and again start by **./startFabric.sh** from the fabric-tool folder and again try to start the network.

To check your development, follow the this [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) for building a Hyperledger Composer blockchain solution.